# Android Studio Evaluate Expression most of the variable return NoSuchFieldError

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, debugging, evaluate

I'm having issue to get my variable value during debug using Evaluate Expression function.
Below is what I received when I tried to get the value via Evaluate Expression. `abc` is a private `var` inside this class and I had `Log` the value and the program can get the value just before this break point with no issue.

[image: Evaluate Expression error]

Full error : `java.lang.NoSuchFieldError : Field not found: MemberDescription(ownerInternalName = folder/currentActivity, name = abc, desc = Z, isStatic = false)`

I'm struggling to debug due to this, need to rely on `Log` which require more time during debugging process.

Additional info:

I'm using M1 Mac

Android Studio Bumblebee | 2021.1.1 Patch 2
Build #AI-211.7628.21.2111.8193401, built on February 17, 2022
Runtime version: 11.0.11+0-b60-7772763 aarch64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
macOS 12.2
GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation
Memory: 2048M
Cores: 8
Registry: external.system.auto.import.disabled=true

Current Kotlin plugin version: 211-1.5.30-release-408-AS7442.40

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Have you found any solution to this?

Comment: I set minify to false for debug version and then only I could start to inspect most of the variables